# c# mysql Parameters.AddWithValue pass NOW()

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am working on a MVC 5 .NET site using C#.  I am trying to simply pass `NOW()` to MYSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue like this:

```
_objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(?time, "NOW()");
```

This does not work because it simply fills in the default `0000-00-00 00:00:00` time.

Comment: You can't do that.  The whole point of a parameter is to be a _value_, not code.

Comment: didn't realize that, thank you

Comment: Countering the downvote on this because I think it's a reasonable question even though it's wrong. Someone else may try to do the same thing, and this will help understand why.